# Setting an Image on Custom TableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to know how can I put an image on the background of the custom cell

The code im using is this one, but this sets all the table to the same image
I want each cell to have its own background depending on who is the message owner
I hope you can helpme this is killing me !

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.messageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatListItem"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatListItem" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    textLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"text"];
    UILabel *userLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    userLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"user"];

    if(usernameText=userLabel){
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat2@2x.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];        
    }
    else{
        UIImageView* img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat1@2x.png"]];
        [cell setBackgroundView:img];
        [img release];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line doesn't look too good to me:

```
if (usernameText=userLabel)
```

should perhaps be:

```
if ([usernameText isEqualToString:userLabel.text])
```

Comment: Almost always, whenever you need to evaluate NSStrings, use isEqualToString: as mentioned by @EarlyRiser

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat1@2x.png"]];
```

Or,

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat1@2x.png"]];